# how to change a combobox based on selection to a number field to 0 on a access form

Tags: .htaccess, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Hey there any help will be appreciated Thanks
I got a combobox field = name(txtCombo)
And a numberField = (txtNumber)

Im getting a error something wrong with my code any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

```
Private Sub txtCombo_Click()
If Me.txtCombo.Value = "Meter" Then
Me.txtNumber.Value = 0
End If
End Sub
```

error imn my code:

Run time error: '2448' You cant assign a value to a object, due to this code I cant continue my calcuation!!!

If I select the Meter value it must change the txtNumber to 0

Comment: What type of field is txtNumber? Text or number? What happens if you put quotation marks around the 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtCombo_AfterUpdate()

If (Me.txtCombo.Value = "Meter") Then

Me.txtNumber.Value = "0"

End If

End Sub
```

If I understand correctly you want the text box value to be set to 0 if meter is selected in the combo box, then this will work, use this code and put it in the after update event in the combox.